# Google app script UiApp DatePicker styling

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Is it possible to style DatePicker object in Google script UiApp? I have tried setStyleAttribute function but it didn't work as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Consider switching to htmlService that will allow using JQuery UI library were you can do almost anything you want...,
A quick search on this forum or on google will bring you to the JQuery datepicker related docs, you'll see it is very attractive :-)